# Is density matrix really a description of 'state'?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

Generally a density matrix is in fact a description of a set of equivalent (experimentally indistinguishable in linear QM) states. So there is no 1-to-1 correspondence between density matrix and 'state', and the density matrix is just a 'coarse-grained' description or tool, let alone somebody claims that there is no 'state' for a subsystem of an entangled system.

From this point of view, it seems it's invalid to define a 'clone' of a mixed state, or to define the entanglement of a mixed state. Especially the 'clone' thing, since we can not clone a 'set' by a single item. Or any item in the 'set' can be regarded as a representative of the set and therefore a valid clone?

Comment: A density matrix is a "statistical state", and may be purified into a pure state on a larger Hilbert space. On this purified state, you may define cloning as usual. I don't really know what you're asking.

Comment: A density matrix describes both quantum states and our knowledge (or better lack of knowledge) about them, so it's actually a very finely controlled tool that lets us model both the quantum dynamics and the classical "information" part about a system.

Comment: A lot of confusion even among scientists who use the density matrix as a tool. It can be used for classical statiscal physics and for quantum physics and for statistical quantum physics. In the later case you would have a distribution of mixed states. If you want to clone a mixed state you need to clone the state of all the particles involved so the density matrix alone doesn't give you enought information. You clone a 'state' not a density matrix.

Comment: The Density matrix represents a 'classically distributed' ensemble of pure states. This means that the constituents of a mixed state are not in a quantum superposition. They are just statistically known. The system is in one of the pure states, we just don't know for sure (that is, with 100% probability). A superposition is different.